# Tango Camera Preview for RGBIR

Tags: java, android, camera, google-project-tango, tango

I am using Tango's demo for videoOverlaySample.

Instead of color, I would like to see the IR data (alone or with color).
So, I replaced TANGO_CAMERA_COLOR with TANGO_CAMERA_RGBIR in both places where it appears.

But screen is black.

Here is the code:

```
/*
 * Copyright 2014 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package com.projecttango.experiments.videooverlaysample;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.atap.tangoservice.Tango;
import com.google.atap.tangoservice.Tango.OnTangoUpdateListener;
import com.google.atap.tangoservice.TangoCameraIntrinsics;
import com.google.atap.tangoservice.TangoCameraPreview;
import com.google.atap.tangoservice.TangoConfig;
import com.google.atap.tangoservice.TangoCoordinateFramePair;
import com.google.atap.tangoservice.TangoEvent;
import com.google.atap.tangoservice.TangoPoseData;
import com.google.atap.tangoservice.TangoXyzIjData;

/**
 * An example showing the usage of TangoCameraPreview class
 * Usage of TangoCameraPreviewClass:
 * To use this class, we first need initialize the TangoCameraPreview class with the activity's 
 * context and connect to the camera we want by using connectToTangoCamera class.Once the connection 
 * is established we need to manually update the TangoCameraPreview's texture by using the
 * onFrameAvailable callbacks.
 * Note:
 * To use TangoCameraPreview class we need to ask the user permissions for MotionTracking 
 * at the minimum level. This is because in Java all the call backs such as 
 * onPoseAvailable,onXyzIjAvailable, onTangoEvents, onFrameAvailable are set together at once. 
 */
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private TangoCameraPreview tangoCameraPreview;
    private Tango mTango;
    private boolean mIsConnected;
    private boolean mIsPermissionGranted;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        tangoCameraPreview = new TangoCameraPreview(this);
        mTango = new Tango(this);
        startActivityForResult(
                Tango.getRequestPermissionIntent(Tango.PERMISSIONTYPE_MOTION_TRACKING),
                Tango.TANGO_INTENT_ACTIVITYCODE);
        setContentView(tangoCameraPreview);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // Check which request we're responding to
        if (requestCode == Tango.TANGO_INTENT_ACTIVITYCODE) {
            // Make sure the request was successful
            if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Motion Tracking Permissions Required!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            } else {
                startCameraPreview();
                mIsPermissionGranted = true;
            }
        }
    }

    // Camera Preview
    private void startCameraPreview() {
        // Connect to color camera
        tangoCameraPreview.connectToTangoCamera(mTango,
                TangoCameraIntrinsics.TANGO_CAMERA_RGBIR);
        // Use default configuration for Tango Service.
        TangoConfig config = mTango.getConfig(TangoConfig.CONFIG_TYPE_DEFAULT);
        config.putBoolean(TangoConfig.KEY_BOOLEAN_DEPTH, true);
        mTango.connect(config);
        mIsConnected = true;

        // No need to add any coordinate frame pairs since we are not using 
        // pose data. So just initialize.
        ArrayList<TangoCoordinateFramePair> framePairs = new ArrayList<TangoCoordinateFramePair>();
        mTango.connectListener(framePairs, new OnTangoUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPoseAvailable(TangoPoseData pose) {
                // We are not using OnPoseAvailable for this app
            }

            @Override
            public void onFrameAvailable(int cameraId) {

                // Check if the frame available is for the camera we want and
                // update its frame on the camera preview.
                if (cameraId == TangoCameraIntrinsics.TANGO_CAMERA_RGBIR) {
                    tangoCameraPreview.onFrameAvailable();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onXyzIjAvailable(TangoXyzIjData xyzIj) {
                // We are not using OnPoseAvailable for this app
            }

            @Override
            public void onTangoEvent(TangoEvent event) {
                // We are not using OnPoseAvailable for this app
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(mIsConnected) {
            mTango.disconnect();
            tangoCameraPreview.disconnectFromTangoCamera();
            mIsConnected = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (!mIsConnected && mIsPermissionGranted) {
            startCameraPreview();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use

```
tangoCameraPreview.connectToTangoCamera(mTango,TangoCameraIntrinsics.TANGO_CAMERA_RGBIR);
```

The Java API does not provide a connectToTangoCamera with the RGBIR, only Color and Fisheye camera (see [here](https://developers.google.com/project-tango/apis/java/reference/TangoCameraPreview))

To display the a depth image instead of the color image, you have to compute the depth image by hand. Therefore you roughly have to:

1. Transform the point cloud with the pose at its given timestamp to the camera frame.
2. Project the point cloud points (x,y,z) to receive the pixel (x,y)
3. You need an array with the resolution of the camera frame (1240x720).
4. Fill up the array with 0 (black).
5. Store the z-value at its given pixel position (upsample your pixels, because the depth camera has only a resolution of 320x180)
6. In OpenGL you can than easly use that array for your texture.

For more details, I recommend you to look into the C example [rgb-depth-sync](https://github.com/googlearchive/tango-examples-c/tree/master/cpp_rgb_depth_sync_example)