# Is it possible to get the Depth Frames using the Java API [google-project-tango]

Tags: java, google-project-tango

Is it possible to get the depth frames from the device (similar to how you would get them from a kinect?)
I can get the pointcloud of the current frame, as well as the rgb frame, but I am looking for the actual depth frames.

I tried just doing

```
     public void onFrameAvailable(final int cameraId) {
                if (cameraId == TangoCameraIntrinsics.TANGO_CAMERA_COLOR) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "NEW COLOR FRAME");
                    }
                if (cameraId == TangoCameraIntrinsics.TANGO_CAMERA_DEPTH) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "NEW DEPTH FRAME");
                }
            }
```

As a test, but the second `if` never passes - so my understanding is that "onFrameAvailable" is never fired on the depth camera - but on the other hand, the camera is obviously working since I can get a pointcloud without any problem.

I also tried looking through the docs and examples, and I could only find examples telling me how to get the pose and the pointcloud for the current frame, but not the depth frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to use connectToTangoCamera with RGBIR. 
I answered that question, how to receive a depth image, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33670475/tango-camera-preview-for-rgbir) more detailed